# Query about Linear dependence of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Please provide a proof or justified explaination to this line from my textbook
" If two elements in a list are equal, the list is linearly dependent."

Comment: It should say "linearly dependent ".

Comment: @Chris Custer sorry my mistake, but..how dependent

Comment: If you have a list of vectors, and two are the same, you can just take zero times all the other vectors, and $v$-$v$ for a nontrivial linear combination equal to zero.

Comment: Put another way, one of the vectors is a linear combination of the other vectors. In particular, $v = 1v$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a set of vectors {$v_1, v_2, ...,v_n$} are linearly dependent if there exist scalars {$a_1, a_2, ...a_n$} **not all equal to 0**, such that $a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n=0$.
Therefore, if $v_i=v_j $ for some $j\neq i$ then you can just choose $a_i=1$, $a_j=-1$ and all the others to be $0$ and by definition they are linearly dependent.